# Hierarchical data matching and displaying

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

In my log files, I have data that represents a the hierarchy of items, much like an http log file might show the hierarchy of a website.

I may have data such as this

```
41 2016-01-01 01:41:32-500 show:category:all
41 2016-01-01 04:11:20-500 show:category:animals
42 2016-01-02 01:41:32-500 show:item:wallaby
42 2016-01-02 01:41:32-500 show:home
```

and I would have 3 items in here... `%{NUMBER:terminal}` `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts}` and `(?<info>([^\r])*)`

I parse the **info** data into an array using `mutate` and `split` to convert `lvl1:lvl2:lvl3` into `['lvl1','lvl2','lvl3']`.

I'm interested in aggregating the data to get counts at various levels easily, such as counting all records where `info[0]` is the same or where `info[0]` and `info[1]` are the same. (and be able to select time range and terminal)

Is there a way to set up kibana to visualize this kind of information?
Or should I change the way the filter is matching the data to make the data easier to access?
the depth of levels varies but I can be pretty certain that the max levels are 5, so I could parse the text into various fields `lvl1` `lvl2` `lvl3` `lvl4` `lvl5` instead of putting them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, I agree with your way of parsing data. But I would like to add on more to make it directly aggregatable & visualize using Kibana.

The approach should be :-

- Filter the data using %{NUMBER:terminal} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts} and (?([^\r])*) {As per information given by you}
- Mutate
- Filter

Then after using mutate & filter you will get data in terms of array {as you have mentioned}

- Now you can add a field as level 1 by mentioning add_field => [ "fieldname", "%{[arrayname][0]}" ]
- Now you can add a field as level 2 by mentioning add_field => [ "fieldname", "%{[arrayname][1]}" ]
- Now you can add a field as level 3 by mentioning add_field => [ "fieldname", "%{[arrayname][2]}" ]

Then you can directly use Kibana to visualize such information.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I've also added another filter for each of the array fields `if [info_1] =~ /%\{info\[0\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "info_1" ]}}` to remove the fields that are empty

Comment: Cool. It would be great if you can share your complete logstash configuration file for other people who are looking for such solutions.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
input {
  file {
      path => "C:/Temp/zipped/*.txt"
      start_position => beginning 
      ignore_older => 0 
      sincedb_path => "C:/temp/logstash_temp2.sincedb"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message","^%{NOTSPACE}\[%{NUMBER:terminal_id}\] %{NUMBER:log_level} %{NUMBER} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ts} \[(?<facility>([^\]]*))\] (?<lvl>([^$|\r])*)"]
  }
  mutate {
       split => ["lvl", ":"]
       add_field => {"lvl_1" => "%{lvl[0]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_2" => "%{lvl[1]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_3" => "%{lvl[2]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_4" => "%{lvl[3]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_5" => "%{lvl[4]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_6" => "%{lvl[5]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_7" => "%{lvl[6]}"}
       add_field => {"lvl_8" => "%{lvl[7]}"}
       lowercase => [ "terminal_id" ] # set to lowercase so that it can be used for index - additional filtering may be required
  }
  date {
     match => ["ts", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ"]
  }
}
filter {
  if [lvl_1] =~ /%\{lvl\[0\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_1" ]}}
  if [lvl_2] =~ /%\{lvl\[1\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_2" ]}}
  if [lvl_3] =~ /%\{lvl\[2\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_3" ]}}
  if [lvl_4] =~ /%\{lvl\[3\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_4" ]}}
  if [lvl_5] =~ /%\{lvl\[4\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_5" ]}}
  if [lvl_6] =~ /%\{lvl\[5\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_6" ]}}
  if [lvl_7] =~ /%\{lvl\[6\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_7" ]}}
  if [lvl_8] =~ /%\{lvl\[7\]\}/ {mutate {remove_field => [ "lvl_8" ]}}
  mutate{
    remove_field => [ "lvl","host","ts" ] # do not keep this data
  }
}


output {
  if [facility] == "mydata" {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "logstash-mydata-%{terminal_id}-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}"
    }
  } else {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "logstash-other-%{terminal_id}-%{+YYYY.MM.DD}"
    }
  }
  # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```